# Responsive menu not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I'm very new to this whole responsive designing in CSS. I just made a working responsive menu and it works fine on my PC when I make the browser-window smaller, but when loading the site on my phone it's just zoomed out and won't show the menu as the responsive one.

[This is the site](http://trinityplay.net/seb/)

I have no clue why it does this, anyone? I've set the maximum width to 900px so my menu actually breaks down if the window is too short.

This is the HTML for the menu:

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li><a href="#">Fonder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Priser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produkter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Frågor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Juridik</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Hem</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And this is the JS:

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
```

And this is the responsive CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
    ul.topnav li {display:none;}
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {position:relative;}
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: none; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        top: 32px;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        /*background-color: red;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code (even if it's 3 lines), I'm proposing an answer.

Comment: why you are using same `max-width:900px` in both `@media` queries

Comment: did you try to use bootstrap 3

Comment: @arunkumartalla I was following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

Comment: Checkout @Amit Kumar's answer. It's the best answer so far coz it prevents you from unnecessarily reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Maviza101 yeah that might actually be a good idea. Though I'll have to remake everything from scratch, won't I? Or is it easy to implement a responsive menu with bootstrap to the current one?

Comment: @Condolent It probably is. All you need to do is to find the right tutorial to follow. That MIGHT not include W3Schools though. When I learned Bootstrap, it was via a short course on edX.org taught by the fantastic Christopher Harrison (https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-bootstrap-tutorial-microsoft-dev203x-1). However, if you're too occupied to take that course, use: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/ or https://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-handling-complex-designs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add a `<meta>` in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To know how to correctly use this `<meta>` (you can put more values in the `content` attribute), you can read this guide :
[Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: This seems interesting! Will try it out

Comment: @Condolent try it, and accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Well, it kind of worked. But it is way too much zoomed in on mobile devices. If you try it you'll notice that the text is wider, is it possible to change the width so it all fits?

Comment: @Condolent It changes your style a lot, I know. This is where you have to find the right properties to work with your project, that's not a too big deal ;)

Comment: Ok, I see! Will play around with it, if it's too much of a hustle then I'll probably look into working with bootstrap. Never used it before so it'll be exciting :)

Comment: @Condolent Yes, always try to do it yourself before using frameworks.  You'll do a better job knowing how it works !

Answer (score 1):

nvbar will work with ajax library. Make sure the jquery is present in the page.  It is easy to design and compatible with mobiles.  For more info, you may refer [to interactive menu with optional sub-menus](https://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/menu/menu-en.html).

```
<nav role="navigation" id="wb-sm" data-ajax-replace="./ajax/sitemenu-en.html" data-trgt="mb-pnl" class="wb-menu visible-md visible-lg" typeof="SiteNavigationElement">
<div class="container nvbar">
<h2>Topics menu</h2>
<div class="row">
<ul class="list-inline menu">
<li><a href="./index-en.html">WET project</a></li>
<li><a href="./docs/start-en.html#implement">Implement WET</a></li>
<li><a href="./docs/start-en.html">Contribute to WET</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Make sure the data-ajax-replace element exists as per the above source in order to display the Menu list and the following footer lines are included at the end.

```
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./wet-boew/js/wet-boew.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap for the responsive sites. It's very easy to implement.
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

You can also create menus using bootstrap as well. Go through below link

[Bootstrap Menus](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Never used bootstrap, will look into it, though! Is it possible to only use the responsive menu from bootstrap and do the rest by myself, somehow? Or will it just be an enormous amount of work?

Comment: If you will use bootstrap you will not face this problem

Comment: A framework is not an answer, even if Bootstrap does the job. It's like repsonding Wordpress when someone wants to know how to build a back-office...